# Is there a seperate Google API Console for creating API Key?

Tags: android-youtube-api

Is there a separate API Console for creating a youtube API key? If so how do I tie that back my application I created in the Googles Developers Console?

Thanks,
-Tony

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I figured it out. From the Google Developer Console I can create the API keys I needed.

-Tony